# Spring Boot jar file reuseable (local maven repository)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have written some generic code for logging and such stuff which I use in all my projects.
I would like to deploy this as a jar file to a local maven repository and include it via dependecies in all of my project.
I'd like to have the code just once and not in every project and share it with other team members.

Is that a good solution? How can I do that?

Comment: Is this inside a company? Do you have a Nexus or Artifactory server?

Comment: Yes, it is inside a company. But this is used only in a subteam, where we don't have a Nexus / Artifactory Server and no possibility to install one. We can only use a file share.

Comment: If want to work with Maven seriously with a team, you need a Maven repository server. Where does your build/ci server deploy the JARs you create?

Comment: The jars are containerized into a docker image. And this docker image is deployed to a local docker registry. The jars are not stored anywhere.

Comment: If the number of projects is small, you might consider putting everything into one multi module project (in one git repository). Then you can let Maven build it automatically in the right order without the need to share JARs. But I would really ask your server admins to run an Artifactory or Nexus for you.